# How to access a setter through an instance of object.create

Tags: javascript

On mozilla website they say:

```
// Example where we create an object with a couple of sample properties.
// (Note that the second parameter maps keys to *property descriptors*.)
o = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
  // foo is a regular 'value property'
  foo: { writable: true, configurable: true, value: 'hello' },
  // bar is a getter-and-setter (accessor) property
  bar: {
    configurable: false,
    get: function() { return 10; },
    set: function(value) { console.log('Setting `o.bar` to', value); }
/* with ES5 Accessors our code can look like this
    get function() { return 10; },
    set function(value) { console.log('setting `o.bar` to', value); } */
  }
});
```

But when I run this code, I can call o.bar but but do I call the set method?

o.bar calls the get, but what do I do to call the set?

Here's the code set up with a fiddle [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/vcvvvveq/)

Comment: Easier than you'd think, I'm guessing: `o.bar = 20;`

Comment: Note, though, that the reference to the variable name in the log statement might not be great:  `var p = o;  p.bar = 20;`  Logs: 'Setting `o.bar` to 20', which might be a little surprising.

Comment: `o.bar = 15` would work and print in the console. However, `o.bar` will still return `10`;

Comment: How do you think can you call `o.bar`? It's a number, not a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set the `o.bar` like this to call the 'set' function:

```
o.bar = 3
Setting `o.bar` to 3
3
```

**EDIT:**

As @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc mentions in the comments, the setter does not set anything in this case. To do so you have to use the input `value` and actually set some (other) value, ex: `this.foo = value`

Comment: I would recommend mentioning that OP's `setter` method doesn't actually set anything.

Comment: Aha! I was expecting o.bar(arg); This is weird!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deal with the issues raised by [@CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2498729/cybernetictwerkguruorc), you can write it like this, storing the actual value in an internal closure variable:

```
o = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
   foo: { writable: true, configurable: true, value: 'hello' },
   bar: (function() {
     var internalValue = 10; 
     return {
       configurable: false,
       get: function() { return internalValue; },
       set: function(value) { 
         console.log('Setting `bar` to', value); 
         internalValue = value;
       }
     };
   }())
});

o.bar; //=> 10
o.bar = 12; // logs 'Setting `bar` to 12'.
o.bar; //> 12
```